# JQuery Tab Selected tab from id

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs

I have 3 tabs in Jquery Ui Tabs. Each tab have different form. How i will get selected tab form  attribute name. I will try like this but i get first tab form name only,

```
$j('input[type=button]').closest("form")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var selected = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
```

More [info](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected)

Comment: Thanks, but as per your code it gives selected tab index only, it does not give <form> id

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=button]') .click(function (){
     $(this).parents("form").attr('name');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this code work first time only. first time i click 1st tab , 2nd tab it work fine, but again i click 1st tab it shows i last clicked means 2nd tab form name

Comment: each page have code like this var frmObjx = $j('input[type=button]').parents("form"); 
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="funXXXX()"></input>
$j(function() {
                alert(frmObjx .attr("id"));
                $j("input[type='text']:first", frmObjx ).focus();
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectedForm = $("#tabs div.ui-tabs-panel:not(.ui-tabs-hide)").children("form");
```